# Pentaho Report Designer 5.0.1 dataRow.get() is not working on Global Scripting

Tags: pentaho, ecmascript-5

I am using PME 5.0.1 as datasource with PRD 5.0.1. On Global Script (ECMAScript) I used dataRow.get("parameterName") to get parameter values on earlier versions on PRD (like 4.5 and 4.8). Generic database connection was used. But now it is not working and throwing exception

```
ReferenceError: "dataRow" is not defined.
```

I have tried with both datasource of .xmi and JNDI. Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling dataRow form inside the init function like so? If not it's a likely reason why dataRow is not defined in your context.

```
function init(dataRow)
{
  var input = dataRow.get('parameterName');
}
```

Commonly you can just click the Template Button after getting in the global scripts tab and it will put the init(dataRow) and other common functions in.

Comment: Actually I used exactly this syntax. But it only works if connection type is generic. Failed for all other type of connection(mine was JNDI)

Comment: I feel that is kinda weird as this seems to be more of a internal function to get the data from Pentaho's input and that the connection type shouldn't matter as maybe we need to manupliate our input first. 

Been banging my head on the reasoning you would get such a result but nothing great has poped in my head yet. Maybe I'll play around with that type of connection and see what results I can get.